# How could my expo app run some task every 5 minutes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, scheduled-tasks

I have an app created with React Native and Expo. I need the app every 5 minutes to launch a notification for the smartphone if new orders are available near the GPS coordinates (even when the app is not opened). I'm trying to figure out how to do it. I already tried to create a BackgroundFetch task that every 5 minutes check in my backend if some order is available, but in the Expo Go the task doesn't run every 5 minutes, it runs randomly. Have someone an idea?

Comment: You might want to look into this SDK supported by Expo: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/

Answer (score 0):

try to use setInterval => "Schedules repeated execution of callback every delay milliseconds."

```
    setInterval(() => {
     sendNotification()
    }, 5000);
```

I hope this helps you.